# VS2015: Can I mark down code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I'm working at someone else's code, sometimes it happens that I've found something useful that I likely will need to return later to.

Except the chances are that I forget where I've found that part and then I need to find it again. Nowadays I'm mostly using breakpoints to set these down, But I don't need these breakpoints for debugging, so I don't think that's the most efficient method. Something that could work for me is a sort of marker that functions marking down like a breakpoint, but does not affect debugging.

Will all these ways of breakpoints, search functions, finding references, and adding a Watches. I do have a feeling that such feature is present in Visual Studio already. But I havn't found it yet, I've already tried searching it up, but it looks like it hasn't asked before.

So, is there a feature in Visual Studio that let you mark down code like breakpoints, but just for the purpose of marking down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to do so.
If I finde something interesting I mark it with a Bookmark.

Just STRG + K, STRK + K and it will be places on your current row.

[image]

With these Buttons you can switch to your bookmarks or delete them all. They are client based.

Visual Studio also gives you a "To Do List" Function. This one is triggered by comments in the code and seen for everyone with the right options used.

[See here how it works in detail.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/06/07/todo-comments-in-the-task-list-2/)

Comment: Ah, wow, There was actually a reason I saw some developers always writing down `//ToDo` in their code, thanks for the help! Both the bookmarks and To Do functions will help me out.

Comment: Yes, with that function Visual Studio keeps track of all the ToDo‘s you write down but probably won’t look back at :b

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called a bookmark. This little toolbar is for bookmarks:

[image]

You can also use the Edit, Bookmarks... menu item and the View, Other Windows, Bookmark Window which among other things lets you see all of them and give them names.

One caveat: the bookmark binds to the line number, and doesn't move if you add or remove lines. So if you bookmark the first line of a function, then make changes above that, the bookmark won't be on the first line of a function any more.